# Laravel, switch from Prod to Dev

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.X

I have transferred my app from dev folder to httpdocs (Prod)

My domain www.domain.com is pointed to the folder httpdocs

My .env is updated

When I tape www.domain.com  I am redirected to my dev folder www.dev.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.env` file located at the root of your project to include:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
I have updated app/Http/Middleware/LangMiddleware